# Convert milliseconds to date (in Excel)

Tags: excel

I have a row in excel with the following data: 1271664970687 (I think it's the number of milliseconds from 1970...).
I would like to have addition row that will show it as date/time.

Answer (score 146):

Converting your value in milliseconds to days is simply `(MsValue / 86,400,000)`

We can get 1/1/1970 as numeric value by DATE(1970,1,1)

```
= (MsValueCellReference / 86400000) + DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Using your value of 1271664970687 and formatting it as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` gives me a date and time of 19/04/2010 08:16:11

Comment: This helped me thanks, but I also have to add the time zone an daylight saving difference from UTC. So, for me the final formula is = (MsValueCellReference / 86400000) + 25569 + TIME(2,0,0) .

Comment: Alternatively for time zone, you can change the formula to `=((MsValueCellReference+(TimezoneOffset*3600000))/86400000)+25569`, so for pacific time, you would enter -8 in for `TimezoneOffset`

Comment: Which is the timezone offset for greenwich meridian?

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins The timezone for the Greenwich Meridian is zero, because GMT _is_ the time at the Greenwich Meridian.

Comment: This provides me with just a number, e.g. 42054,68297. How do I turn that into a date?

Comment: Use the Excel cell formatting, and specify a date format on the cell.

Comment: For me to get this to work I needed to use 86400 as the divisor; not 86,400,000. Obviously my timestamps are less exact-- in seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: Team, I have to implement the below formula (convert millisec to DATE format) in the middle of my code ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/86400000)+DATE(1970,1,1)" but how can i check if the RC[-1] value is NON BLANK or NOT EMPTY before i apply this formula? Please suggest!! Thanks in advance. –

Comment: Depends on what you want to show if that's the case. I think IF and ISBLANK will be what you need here:
`=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]), "not available", (RC[-1]/86400000+DATE(1970,1,1)))`

Substitute "not available" for whatever value you want to see if your cell is blank.

Answer (score 3):

See [Converting unix timestamp to excel date-time](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=130691) forum thread.