# Miliseconds to Excel causing 4 year difference in date

Tags: linux, windows, macos, excel, date

**Edit**:In order to be more of a help to more users, I've updated this question with more keywords so everyone with this problem in the future can fix it easily. (Thanks for the answer!)

I've checked this question [Convert milliseconds to date (in Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666112/convert-miliseconds-to-date-in-excel) to convert my miliseconds to datetime in Excel.

However!

Here are 3 values I'm trying to convert as example: 
1375540284420
1375540284786
1375540284788

This site: http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.UsbP4_TuLig gives me Sat Aug 03 2013 16:31:24 GMT+0200 as answer to the first miliseconds I've posted above.

However, Excel gives me 14:31 04-08-2017

What am I missing? Could you please help me out, I've tried several conversions now but none are correct.

Thanks advance

Comment: I'm getting the same date both with Excel and with the site you linked. PS: The site you linked is taking into consideration the timezone, you you have to take 2 hours from 16:31 to have it 14:31. With the formula in the question you linked to, I get the same date and time.

Comment: @Jerry How is it possible I get 2017 vs 2013 on the website? Do you get the correct 2013 date?

Comment: Yup. I don't know how you got that date. I'm getting 14:31 03-08-13 all right. You're using `= (1375540284420 / 86400000) + 25569` from the question you linked right?

Comment: Excel gives me 2017 on that one.. FML

Comment: Maybe you mistyped a formatting? You used `hh:mm dd-mm-yy`, right? I made a google spreadsheet too [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dFlEYUI4N1pKSGRTN3F4TWZrb0t2ZGc&usp=sharing). (it's just that it doesn't have a proper custom formatting option, but the date is right)

Comment: The original sheet was created on a mac. I've downloaded @Jerry his file and added my content in it. I calculated the miliseconds to datetime using that sheet and now everything works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macintoshes generally use the 1904 date system, that nowadays is offset by 1462 days from the 1900 date system, ‘inherited’ by M$ from Lotus123 and so deliberately including a one (‘Leap Year’) day discrepancy for a period. (For details see [Dates And Times In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm).)

The date system is workbook specific and can be controlled in Excel Options under Advanced, When calculating this workbook. A book created in Mac and opened in Windows etc will have the relevant flag set.

Advice on the site linked above includes:

`Unless absolutely required, you should never use the 1904-system.  If you change systems after you've entered some dates in a workbook, these dates will appear to be off 4 years (because the serial dates haven't changed, only their display representation has).  Moreover, linking workbooks with different date systems will cause problems.`

Comment: Chip says that 1900 system counts days from `1900-Jan-0` and 1904 system from `1904-Jan-0` - that latter date is incorrect, 1904 system counts from `Jan 1`

Comment: @pnuts that would do it, but would be a "work-around". I'd rather change the date to be matching with the most common one. Thanks for your answer.